# PHP - sort array by array key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array in PHP:

In PHP APIs I have this array and want to sort ot by custom_price, but not getting how to acheive so ..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1204
            [custom_price] => 33.1500
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1199
            [custom_price] => 16.83
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1176
            [custom_price] => 16.83
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1173
            [custom_price] => 11.73
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1170
            [custom_price] => 22.5
        )
)
```

How i can sort from .. high to low & low to high .. by custom_price

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `usort`:

**high to low**

```
usort($input, function ($a, $b) {return $a['custom_price'] < $b['custom_price'];});
print_r( $input );
```

**low to high**

```
usort($input, function ($a, $b) {return $a['custom_price'] > $b['custom_price'];});
print_r( $input );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Keep in mind this is Deprecated in 8+ must return Int values

Using `usort`:

**String Comparison**:

Reference this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382799/what-happened-in-php8-0-0-to-break-usort-intstrlenastrlenb)

**Int Comparison**

*Descending*

```
usort($sidebarData ->rankingData, function ($a, $b) { 
if ($a->integerProperty == $b->intergerProperty)
{
   return 0;

} 
return ($a->integerProperty < $b->integerProperty) ? 1 : -1;});
```

*Ascending*

```
usort($sidebarData ->rankingData, function ($a, $b) { 
if ($a->integerProperty == $b->intergerProperty)
{
   return 0;

} 
return ($a->integerProperty < $b->integerProperty) ? -1 : 1;});
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution might help you.

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['custom_price'] - $b['custom_price'];
}

usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
```

Or

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}

aasort($your_array,"custom_price");
```

here is reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

> use `array_multisort()` with `SORT_DESC` and `SORT_ASC`

```
<?php

    $MYarray=
    array(
    0 => array(
           "id"=> 1204,
           "custom_price"=> 33.1500
        ),
    1 =>  array(
           "id"=> 1199,
           "custom_price"=> 16.83
        ),
    2 => array(
           "id"=> 1176,
           "custom_price"=> 316.83
        ));


    $custom_price = array();
    foreach ($MYarray as $key => $row)
    {
        $custom_price[$key] = $row['custom_price'];
    }

    array_multisort($custom_price, SORT_DESC, $MYarray);


    var_dump($MYarray);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Ksort](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_ksort.asp)**

```
$age=array("1204"=>"33.1500","1199"=>"16.83","1176"=>"11.73");
ksort($age);

foreach($age as $x=>$x_value)
   {
    echo "Value=" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
   }
```

Output

```
Value=11.73
Value=16.83
Value=33.1500
```

**Tip:** Use the krsort() function to sort an associative array in descending order, according to the key.

**Tip:** Use the asort() function to sort an associative array in ascending order, according to the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Descending order 
    function sortByDecOrder($a, $b) {
        return $b['custom_price'] - $a['custom_price'];
    }

    usort($arr, 'sortByOrder');
// Ascending order 
function sortByAscOrder($a, $b) {
        return $b['custom_price'] - $a['custom_price'];
    }

    usort($arr, 'sortByOrder');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usort` function

```
<?php 
$array = array( 
            "0" => array (
               "id" => 1204,
               "custom_price" => 33.1500    
            ),

            "1" => array (
               "id" => 1199,
               "custom_price" => 20.83  
            ),

            "2" => array (
               "id" => 1176,
               "custom_price" => 19.83  
            )
         );

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['custom_price'] - $b['custom_price'];
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

[check the desired output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62788a7c2c99aa487492cc7344538bd198213787)