# usort() gives unexpected result while sorting by a column with float values

Tags: php, sorting, floating-point, comparison, usort

Today I provided the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636675/php-sort-array-by-array-key/50636792#50636780) and I wrote a script, but I found out that something went wrong.

Here is the first script

```
<?php 
$array = array( 
            "0" => array (
               "id" => 1204,
               "custom_price" => 33.1500    
            ),
            
            "1" => array (
               "id" => 1199,
               "custom_price" => 15.83  
            ),
            
            "2" => array (
               "id" => 1176,
               "custom_price" => 16.83  
            )
         );

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['custom_price'] - $b['custom_price'];
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

and its output is (also you can check [output on sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c09df339b394c60e1a04a06ad2ef26573e91453))

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1176
            [custom_price] => 16.83
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1199
            [custom_price] => 15.83
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1204
            [custom_price] => 33.15
        )

)
```

So, my desired output should be sort like (`custom_price 15.83, 16.83, 33.15000`) but the actual output is (`custom_price 16.83,15.83,33.15000`). you can see 15.83 is smallest from 16.83. the sorting result is wrong

So, when I change custom_price 15.83 to 14.83 then sorting output is correct

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1199
            [custom_price] => 14.83
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1176
            [custom_price] => 16.83
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1204
            [custom_price] => 33.15
        )

)
```

[you can see output on sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d8b595b8296cb76c84ba6348021c9aa0399f004)

I can't understand what's going on.. any idea about this ?

**My Question is:** I check each iteration but can't identify the problem. when custom_price is 15.83 then result is wrong. why?

Comment: you need to use `-1` or `0` or `1` when sorting float values

Comment: @Ghost when custom_price is 15.83 then result is wrong. other wise result is ok. i am refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: You're problem is you're using '-' to compare rather than <, = or > this results in other consequences you get the desired result by changing 15.83 to 15.82 due to a rounding issue. See Nigel Ren's complete answer below.

Comment: @TommyBs Nigel Ren's answer is fine. i got my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a warning in the PHP manual about the return values from the `usort()` compare function (at http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#refsect1-function.usort-parameters)...

> **Caution** Returning non-integer values from the comparison function,
>   such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the
>   callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be
>   cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as
>   equal.

Also from PHP 7. you can use the spaceship operator [`<=>`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) which returns 1, 0, -1 depending on the comparison of the two values...

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['custom_price'] <=> $b['custom_price'];
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a complete example in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#example-6182) about `usort`. Here's the modified version to solve your problem:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['custom_price'] == $b['custom_price']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['custom_price'] < $b['custom_price']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will solve your problem,

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['custom_price']==$b['custom_price']) return 0;
    return $a['custom_price'] > $b['custom_price'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated function

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['custom_price'] > $b['custom_price'];
});
```