# Error installing Jornal 3 template on OpenCart

Tags: php, templates, opencart

I installed jornal3 on OcStore, imported demo 6, and got the error:

> Unknown: uksort (): Returning bool from comparison function is
> deprecated, return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than
> zero in / home / l / lllci / optovik / public_html / system / library
> / journal3 / options / parser.php on line 297Unknown: uksort ():
> Returning bool from comparison function is deprecated, return an
> integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero in / home / l /
> lllci / optovik / public_html / system / library / journal3 / options
> / parser.php on line 297Warning: Undefined variable $ loader in
> /home/l/lllci/optovik/public_html/system/storage/modification/system/library/template/twig.php
> on line 49

Comment: It can be related to PHP version. IF you use php8. version try to switch to the php7. Or ask Journal developers to fix that problem.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382799/what-happened-in-php8-0-0-to-break-usort-intstrlenastrlenb

Comment: @K.B. Changing php version from 8. to 7. didn't help. Where can I find the Jornal developers?

Comment: There where you bought Journal theme should be some link where you can place the  support ticket.