# Wrong result usort PHP 8

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have the following code which should sort 'BMW' to the first position:

```
$cars=['Toyota','Volvo','BMW'];
usort($cars,function($v){return $v <=> 'BMW';});
var_export($cars);
```

The result with PHP7 (and smaller) is correct:

```
array ( 0 => 'BMW', 1 => 'Volvo', 2 => 'Toyota', )
```

As far as I understand, the result with PHP8 is wrong.

```
array (0 => 'Volvo', 1 => 'BMW', 2 => 'Toyota',)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/8SCXk

It's not up to the spaceship operator. This one seems to be working correctly. The cause must lie in the behavior of usort.

```
var_dump(
    'Volvo' <=> 'BMW',
    'BMW' <=> 'Volvo',
    'BMW' <=> 'Toyota',
    'Toyota' <=> 'BMW',
    'BMW' <=> 'BMW'
    );
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/UaKrM

My question: Is this a nasty bug in PHP8 or do I need to change my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what happened in PHP8.0.0 to break usort(...(int)(strlen($a)<strlen($b)));?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382799/what-happened-in-php8-0-0-to-break-usort-intstrlenastrlenb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the wrong callback function, you'll get the wrong result. It should be:

```
$cars = ['Toyota', 'Volvo', 'BMW'];
usort($cars, function ($a, $b) { return $a <=> $b; });
var_export($cars);
```

Notice the second parameter `$b` and how it is used.

See: [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and an example here: https://3v4l.org/X1DVU

The difference you see with older PHP versions is indeed caused by PHP 8 switching to sable sorting, but this is irrelevant in your case.

Comment: I had a total blackout. Thanks.

Comment: @jspit It happens to all of us. Took me quite a while before I spotted it.